# Sort dictionary by key with highest frequency

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of dictionaries. And want to return an orderedDictionary sorted by frequency(most to least) of key.

```
 data = [{'123':'abc'}, {'123':'def'}, {'125':'123'}, {'125':'123243'}, {'125':'12312'} ]
```

My approach was to get frequency of each key and then return a dictionary with the appropriate key-value pairs.
This is what I tried, but this doesnt seem to be the most pythonic way of approaching this problem. Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
freq_dict = {}
    for x_dict in data:
        for key in x_dict:
            if key in freq_dict:
                freq_dict[key] = freq_dict[key] + 1
            else:
                freq_dict[key] = 1
    s = [(k, freq_dict[k]) for k in sorted(freq_dict, key=freq_dict.get, reverse=True)] 
    print(s)
```

Comment: to be clear: what you want is a LIST of dictionaries- each of which has only one key and one value- sorted in order of the most frequently occurring key? does the order of the dictionaries with the same key matter?

Comment: They key are not unique. In my example above the result would be something like ` [ {'125':'123'}, {'125':'123243'}, {'125':'12312'},{'123':'abc'}, {'123':'def'}]  `

Comment: by the way: surround your code with backticks to mark it as code formatted. like this: \`<code>\`. you can do this in a post or a comment.

Comment: Again, to be clear- the square brackets indicate a LIST, and each set of curly braces is a separate dictionary, correct? So this is supposed to be a list of dictionaries, each dictionary with one entry?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. list of dictionaries with one entry for each dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
from collections import Counter

# input data
data = [{'123': 'abc'}, {'123': 'def'}, {'125': '123'}, {'125': '123243'}, {'125': '12312'}]

# count occurrence of first key in each dict in list
# this produces a dictionary with the data's keys
# ('123', '125', etc) as keys and the counts as values
counts = Counter([list(d.keys())[0] for d in data])

# sort by descending frequency of keys
data_sorted = sorted(
    data,
    key=lambda item: counts[list(item.keys())[0]], # function to lookup freq from counts
    reverse=True # descending order
)

print(data_sorted)
```

This results in:

```
[{'125': '123'}, {'125': '123243'}, {'125': '12312'}, {'123': 'abc'}, {'123': 'def'}]
```

The answer assumes that each dictionary in your data list will be of unity length.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to get the frequency of your dictionary keys is to [use a `collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). This works like so:

```
from collections import Counter

freq = Counter(k for d in data for k in d)
```

Now `freq` is a dictionary that has each of the keys as a key, and how many times that key appears is the value. Sort that dictionary into a list of keys- in ascending order- using `sorted` and the optional `key` argument:

```
freq_list = sorted(freq, key=freq.get)
```

Use `.reverse()` to switch the list in-place to descending order:

```
freq_list.reverse()
```

Finally, create your final sorted list again using the `sorted` function, with the optional `key` parameter referring to the `index` method of your `freq_list` (with the key of the dictionary as the argument- we use a lambda to make that happen):

```
result = sorted(data, key = lambda d: freq_list.index(list(d)[0]))
```

Explanation of the `key` parameter of `sorted`: this parameter is any function that accepts one argument. The `sorted` algorithm takes the value that it doesn't know what to do with and executes the `key` function on that value. The result of that function determines the sorting order.

So for example, when supplying the `get()` method of a dictionary, the result will be sorted according to natural order of the associated dictionary *values* since `get` returns a value from a given key. When supplying the `index()` method of a list, the item sort order will match the order of the items in that other list.

Comment: freq_list.reverse() could be avoided by using reverse=True as part of the sorted function.

Comment: @jsp right I saw that in the other answer (I had already written mine btw- was busy doing other things at the same time) - wasn't aware that existed. i'll leave mine as-is though.