# Python - How do I sort a dictionary by VALUE with highest frequency

Tags: python, sorting

For example I have

[{1: '100', 2: '102', 3: '101', 4: '100', 5: '102', 6: '100', 7: '102', 8: '101', 9: '100'}]

I want to sort it into

[{1: '100', 4: '100', 6: '100', 9: '100', 2: '102', 5: '102', 7: '102', 3: '101', 8: '101'}]

So it must be based solely on which value is most common.

Someone did it with sorting based on the key: [Sort dictionary by key with highest frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066776/sort-dictionary-by-key-with-highest-frequency)

I could'nt figure it out please help! Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages. [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
from collections import Counter

dic={1: '100', 2: '102', 3: '101', 4: '100', 5: '102', 6: '100', 7: '102', 8: '101', 9: '100'}

value_counts = Counter(dic.values())
#print(value_counts) # Counter({'100': 4, '102': 3, '101': 2})

#Credit to @stef..!
res = dict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: value_counts[x[1]], reverse=True))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: '100', 4: '100', 6: '100', 9: '100', 2: '102', 5: '102', 7: '102', 3: '101', 8: '101'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input** Dictonary Given,

```
a = [{1: '100', 2: '102', 3: '101', 4: '100', 5: '102', 6: '100', 7: '102', 8: '101', 9: '100'}]
```

**Find the Count of the values** in dict a.

```
from collections import Counter
a_counted_dict = Counter(a[0].values())
print("Counted Value dict : "+str(a_counted_dict))
```

Counted Value dict : Counter({'100': 4, '102': 3, '101': 2})

**Sort Dictonary By Its Key,**

```
a_sorted_by_key = dict(sorted(a[0].items()))
print(a_sorted_by_key)
```

{1: '100', 2: '102', 3: '101', 4: '100', 5: '102', 6: '100', 7: '102', 8: '101', 9: '100'}

**Again Sort Dictonary By Its Value,** So that same value will combined,

```
a_sorted_by_key_and_value = dict(sorted(a_sorted_by_key.items(), key=lambda item:item[1]))
print(a_sorted_by_key_and_value)
```

{1: '100', 4: '100', 6: '100', 9: '100', 3: '101', 8: '101', 2: '102', 5: '102', 7: '102'}

**Again Sort Dictonary By Couted frequency,**

```
a_sorted_by_key_and_value_and_valuefrequency = dict(sorted(a_sorted_by_key_and_value.items(), key=lambda item: a_counted_dict[item[1]], reverse= True))
```

{1: '100', 4: '100', 6: '100', 9: '100', 2: '102', 5: '102', 7: '102', 3: '101', 8: '101'}

That is your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code to sort the items in a dictionary:

```
[{1: '100', 2: '102', 3: '101', 4: '100', 5: '102', 6: '100', 7: '102', 8: '101', 9: '100'}]
l2=[] #---> empty list to store the sorted values
l1=[{1: '100', 2: '102', 3: '101', 4: '100', 5: '102', 6: '100', 7: '102', 8: '101', 9: '100'}]#-->Provided list
l4=sorted(l1[0].items(), key=lambda item: item[1])#--> Lamda Function, sorted method and items method is used to store the sorted data in the form of tuple
l2.append(dict((x, y) for x, y in l4))#--> change the tuple back to dictionary and store in append in the empty list
print(l2)
```